# chrome.storage seems to lose state after switching back-and-forth between tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Background**

I am currently building a chrome extension collects cookies for the active tab and stores these in chrome.storage.local as a JSON string (popup.html) before being redirected to a different popup (cookie_popup.html). The stored cookies are then used to populate a table to display the contents. This works fine as long as I do not switch between browser tabs, I can open- and close the popup (cookie_popup.html) as often as I want while getting the desired effect.

**The problem**

When I navigate to another tab the table is no longer populated and chrome.storage.local just returns an empty object. chrome.storage.local seemed to have cleared but *only* for the stored cookies, not any of the other states that I have stored. I hope somebody can help me understand why.

**What I have tried**

I have tried changing chrome.storage.local to chrome.storage.sync, nothing changed. I also made sure that the cookies were not accidentally set again upon loading a new tab.

**The code**

The tabHandler that sets cookies in storage (popup.html - only called on button press).

```js
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabHandler);

    function tabHandler(tabs) {
        chrome.cookies.getAll({url: tabs[0].url}, function(cookies) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({cookiejar: JSON.stringify(cookies)});
        });
    }
```

Populating the cookie table (cookie_popup.html).

```js
    chrome.storage.local.get('cookiejar', function(value) {

        try {
            let jar = JSON.parse(value.cookiejar);
            // ... Snipped ...
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            warningAlert.style = 'display: block;';
            warningAlert.innerText = 'Could not parse cookies; Please restart process.';
        }
    });
```

Whenever opening a different tab and opening the extension popup the JSON parsing fails because value.cookiejar is an empty object.

Comment: More likely `cookiejar` is set to `undefined`.

Comment: You are correct in the sense `value.cookiejar` is `undefined` as `value` is a empty object when I try to retrieve the _cookiejar from storage_. I do not understand why it _unsets itself_ after I switch tabs, but not as long as I stay on the tab where the cookies have been _set_ to storage. This also happens after I change back to the tab they were originally set on.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that `cookies` is `undefined`, I don't know what that is because I don't know what is the value of `tabs[0].url` when you're calling `chrome.cookies.getAll`. Is not evident that you do that when the tab is changed or even if the domain on that tab has set any cookies.

Comment: Your code always writes into the same key `cookiejar` regardless of a tab. It means the value is overwritten. You should store the data using a unique key per each tab. Maybe use the tab's id. Or maybe just utilize sessionStorage inside the content script. There are many solutions, probably. BTW there's no need for JSON.stringify/parse when using chrome.storage.local as it can store simple objects/arrays by design.